# Props passed to functional component change automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, bootstrap-4, frontend

I am working on an experimental project and I was trying playing around with javascript when I encountered this weird thing that I have no explanation for its behavior.I am using bootstrap 4 with CDN.   [SandboxCode](https://codesandbox.io/s/l5w09j9z6z?autoresize=1&codemirror=1&eslint=1&expanddevtools=1&hidenavigation=1&moduleview=1&previewwindow=tests)

```
import React from 'react';

const Button = props => {
  const showProps = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(props.day, props.slot);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Click Me!
      </div>

      <div className="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div className="modal-dialog">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h4 className="modal-title">Add / Edit Slot</h4>
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                &times;
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                    <h6>Faculty</h6>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                    <h6>Venue</h6>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>
                    <h6>Subject</h6>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="btn btn-success btn-cons btn-block"
                  onClick={showProps}
                >
                  Save
                </button>
              </form>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger btn-block"
                data-dismiss="modal"
              >
                Close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

this component provides a button which opens a modal when the Save button is clicked inside the modal then it console's two props (day and slot).

Its parent component is the main component which is then used In the App.js file to be rendered.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "./Button/Button";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return ["Monday", "Tuesday"].map((day, dayIndex) => {
      return [0, 1].map((slot, slotIndex) => {
        return (
          <Button key={dayIndex + "-" + slotIndex} day={day} slot={slotIndex} />
        );
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Excepted Result:- Upon clicking the button and clicking the save button in modal, each button should console different data depending on props.

Output:- All the save button clicks output the same thing.
I have been stuck on this for two days now and I have tried a lot of things.

Comment: Hi mate, I've create a sandbox with your code and it seems to run fine, check if you can se logged what do you expect: https://codesandbox.io/s/mj8yryw14p

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini 
I don't see you using bootstrap, so can you please try https://codesandbox.io/s/l5w09j9z6z?autoresize=1&codemirror=1&eslint=1&expanddevtools=1&hidenavigation=1&moduleview=1&previewwindow=tests this one

Comment: It is really wrong to work with ids in react as it is an anti-pattern. You should work with refs instead or with approriate UI kit like React Semantic UI

Comment: What does this have to do with functional programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an `id` issue :). Look at the below code:

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Make the `id` unique for every modal, otherwise no matter which button you click, it will bring up the modal for the first element it finds with the given id.

See the fixed code in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8lqy01pvz9), basically changed these two lines to ensure a unique modal id:

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target={`#myModal_${props.day}_${props.slot}`}>
```

And

```
<div className="modal fade" id={`myModal_${props.day}_${props.slot}`}>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, can you explain in brief what the problem was

Comment: The value of id attribute must be unique on the page. As it was not the case, no matter which button was clicked, bootstrap js was finding the first modal with the given id and displaying that.

Comment: It is really wrong to work with ids in react as it is an anti-pattern. You should work with refs instead or with approriate UI kit like React Semantic UI

Comment: While I agree there are better ways to implement this use case (modals) in React, there are other valid scenarios, like integrating a component with traditional code, where one must know how to deal with issues like this one.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone, hugely appreciated. As I agree completely that's its an anti-pattern, but that being said, as I mentioned above that this no more than a big experiment of how far can I go breaking rules and patching stuff. Thank you once again